# progressbar not showing on android version 4.1 or above

Tags: android

progress bar not show  in android version above 4.0, and below is my code which work fine on 2.2 or above but not show in 4.1 version of android mobile any idea why? i am using background `getDataTask extends AsyncTask` to get data from url. problem is ProgressBar visible in android version 2.2 to 4.0 but not show in 4.1 any idea why??

here is my code:

```
   <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:paddingTop="100dp" />`
```

My Manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.schoollunchapp"
 android:versionCode="1"
 android:versionName="1.0" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/imagelogostartup"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <!--    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/> --> 
    <activity
        android:name="com.schoollunchapp.SplashScreen" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name= ".HomeMenu"  android:screenOrientation="portrait"  ></activity>      
   </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: progress bar not show in android 4.1 any idea why??? is wrk fine in 2.3

Comment: i edit my code please check this spinner show in 2.2 also on 4.2 off simulator but not show in 4.1 version of real device tell me why??

Comment: Your progress bar works for me on 4.1 and above. Please add additional detail to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should not add your progress bar into your manifest file.

create new layout for your activity and add this to there.

Comment: how to addprogressbar in manifiest??? how is working on 2.2 4.0? why not work on 4.1??